# Are all the devices which support BLE 4.0 can be connected in my iOS devices which support BLE 4.0?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

About Bluetooth Low Energy. I know iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPad 3 with iOS 5.1 and above support BLE 4.0. And I read the sample code TemperatureSensor from Apple. My question is what is the requirement for the sensors? In another words, what kind of sensors can be connected in this application? Are all the devices which support BLE 4.0 can be connected in my iOS devices which support BLE 4.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BLE communication is based on GATT (General Attributes), which is essentially an exchanges of the values of different characteristics under a service. If you've read the TemperatureSensor sample code, you must have seen that it starts to discover devices according to a service UUID, and then read/write characteristics, still based on UUID, under the service. Therefore, as long as the sensor supports BLE and you know about its services (its UUID, its characteristics and properties), you can program your iOS app to communicate with it. Some of the services are 'pre-defined' by Bluetooth SIG, so you can find the information of these services on  [Bluetooth SIG website](http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/GATT-Specification-Documents.aspx).

Comment: One thing is not very clear about the UUID. Do you mean I have to know UUID of BLE device (sensor) before I connect? Different BLE devices have different UUIDs? Or in another word when I buy a new BLE device, it should provide a UUID with it so that I can add the id to my program before I can connect to it? Thanks.

Comment: @bagusflyer In BLE, everything (Device,Service,Characteristic) is assigned an UUID. But you don't need to know the device UUID to connect to them. Instead, you can always scan nearby devices and connect to them, and then scan the service on that peripheral. But it will be wise for you to know the service UUID to identify those that provide this service. For example, if you know the UUID for the SERVICE 'temperature' is 0xabcd, you can then only deal with those peripheral providing the service buy calling 'scanForPeripheralsWithServices:' with UUID 0xabcd as the argument for this function.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can connect any BLE device to a BLE supported iOS device.

In regards to the example code you're talking about, it looks for a specific service UUID for temperature sensors:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];
```

Being as there are no temperature sensors on the market that I could find, you may want to use nil to scan for any and all devices:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

To experiment with this, you can use the app [LightBlue](http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/34242179806/simulate-ble-peripherals-with-lightblue-1-2) or [iTunes Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) which lets you turn your iPhone into a peripheral with any services / characteristics you define.